# Pycharm Python "can't open file","[Error 2] No such file or directory"

Tags: python, pycharm

Whenever i try to run main.py i get this error 'can't open file PATH\main.py': [Errno 22] Invalid argument'
And after running second time file get deleted or disappears
How can I fix it?

Comment: Starting a new project would be the fast way.

Comment: Update I was Working on a keylogger project and i was was using pynput but when i run other files it works

Answer (score 0):

I believe [Errno 22] is typically due to invalid inputs.

I would check if the file path is correct (including format such as .py at the end) and maybe try using / or \  instead of a single \ for windows.